deployment on NOC- Planethoster node.js / react app
I'm a little lost in deploying my app on noc (Planethoster).
I created my node application in Planethoster. I transferred my backend to the folder created and installed the dependencies using (npm i).
For the front end, I made the build and inserted all the build files in the public_html folder.
When I launch the server, my site is displayed but as soon as I refresh or go to another page, I get a 404 error. I think it's because Express doesn't send me to the react-router so I've made this on my server.js but it doesn't work.
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public_html")));

app.get("*", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public_html", "index.html"));
});

I already tried to change public_html -> public.
Perhaps someone has a solution?
Thanks a lot!
